# WPF overwrite all default mouse cursors

Tags: wpf, styles, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to change all default cursors (defined by .NET) to changed into other cursors for a single skin style? I mean that if the mouse touch the current window **all** default cursors from the defined style should be used.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `Mouse.OverrideCursor` property to globaly change the `Cursor` for the whole `WPF` application

Example:

```
 Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I mean. I want set the default cursor for each OS cursor temporary, e. g. I set the hand and the arrow cursor to some other cursor file. If the programmer use the hand cursor (Window.Cursor = Cursors.Hand) not the default Hand cursor from OS is shown, the in style defined cursor file is shown instead.

Ergo, I replace all defined default cursors (hand, arrow, ...) with custom cursor files only for this style.

I hope you can understood what I want to say.

Thanks.